# Rails + Rake: How to simulate running of rake task to see if it works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Is there a way to do a test run of a rake task? If so what is the command to do it? I don't want to actually touch the development database since my task manipulates the data.

Comment: If it shouldn't touch the data, what 'simulation' do you want it to do?  You can use a secondary environment that uses some other database (sqlite, if you want to keep it really simple).

Comment: You could clone the dev DB into the test DB (how you do this will depend on what DB you're running) then run the rake task in the test enviroment: `rake task_name RAILS_ENV=test`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can actually run `bundle exec rake COMMAND -n`

Having a look at rakes help we can see it here.

```
# rake --help
--dry-run Do a dry run without executing actions.
```